# How to run react app in subdirectory on xampp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a react project.

It runs normally in htdocs directory on xampp server, but in a subdirectory doesn't display the react page.

I want to know a method to run my react app in a subdirectory on xampp server.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
- Open httpd.conf
- Find tag DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
- change the path to the subdirectory you need.

Hope this helps.